# How many Remote Nodes can Jenkins manage

Tags: jenkins

How many Remote Nodes can Jenkins manage ? Are there any limitations/memory issues?

What is more effective:
1) 100 Nodes 1 executor per node ?
2) 5 Nodes with 20 executors per node ?

Tx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no limitation on # of nodes one can have although your system might feel like saying, *enough is enough!* Issues such as number of processes per user (we got this issue recently, not with Jenkins but some other application where RAM and disk space were fine but the system stopped responding. We started getting `system cannot fork() error`), total number of open files etc. Few such issues might still be configurable but may not be allowed/feasible.

If resource (in your case, nodes) is not a constraint, which process wouldn't like to run wild? :) In practical cases, generally you wouldn't have the flexibility to opt for first option. In second case where you have 5 nodes with 20 executors, all you have to make sure is *not to tie up jobs to a particular node* unless you have a compelling reason.

Some slaves are faster, while others are slow. Some slaves are closer (network wise) to a master, others are far away. So doing a good build distribution is a challenge. Currently, Jenkins employs the following strategy:

1. If a project is configured to stick to one computer, that's always honored.
2. Jenkins tries to build a project on the same computer that it was previously built.
3. Jenkins tries to move long builds to slaves, because the amount of network interaction between a master and a slave tends to be logarithmic to the duration of a build (IOW, even if project A takes twice as long to build as project B, it won't require double network transfer.) So this strategy reduces the network overhead.

You should also have a look at these links:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Least+Load+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin

Comment: FYI, I ran some tests and it looks that less slaves with more executors is much better.

Comment: So i assume that you also tried more number of slaves with less executors per slave option.

Comment: Indeed, 200 slaves with 1 exe. Jenkins reboot took ~30M (200 ssh reconnects).

Comment: If reboot was the only concern w.r.t your original question, then in that case, IMO, given same number of jobs in both cases, more # of slaves should anytime take more time to come up.